# How to use str detect regex to create a new column with tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

Consider the data

```
X1
apple1
orange
apple3
apple4
red
green
abc
xyz 
w2
```

I want to create a new column so that all the apples are in its own column

for example

```
X1         apples
apple1     apple1
orange     NA
apple3     apple3
apple4     apple4
red        NA
green      NA
abc        NA
xyz        NA
w2         NA
```

The data is given by

```
data = read_csv("some.csv")
```

What i tried

```
data %>% mutate(apples = str_detect(X1, "apple"))
```

That would just be true and false unsure how to do what i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use `ifelse` along with `grepl` here:

```
data$apples <- ifelse(grepl("apple", data$X1, fixed=TRUE), data$X1, NA)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `startsWith` if `"apple"` always comes at the beginning of the string.

```
transform(df, apples = replace(X1, !startsWith(X1, 'apple'), NA))

#      X1 apples
#1 apple1 apple1
#2 orange   <NA>
#3 apple3 apple3
#4 apple4 apple4
#5    red   <NA>
#6  green   <NA>
#7    abc   <NA>
#8    xyz   <NA>
#9     w2   <NA>
```

---

Using `str_detect` we can do :

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% mutate(apples = replace(X1, !str_detect(X1, 'apple'), NA))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(X1 = c("apple1", "orange", "apple3", "apple4", 
"red", "green", "abc", "xyz", "w2")), row.names = c(NA, -9L), 
class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(data$X1, "apple.*")
```

Answer (score 0):

An option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[grepl('apple', X1), apples := X1]
df
#       X1 apples
#1: apple1 apple1
#2: orange   <NA>
#3: apple3 apple3
#4: apple4 apple4
#5:    red   <NA>
#6:  green   <NA>
#7:    abc   <NA>
#8:    xyz   <NA>
#9:     w2   <NA>
```